# Styling an <hr> tag

Tags: html, css, padding

I am creating a line on my html page, it goes above my navigation panel. The fiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/rupsdino1997/1md3phmo/

HTML:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Feline</title>
<link href="Styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="top">

      <h1 style="font-size:60px">L'Auberge De Napoleon III</h1>
      <hr style="background-color: red; height: 4px; position: relative; bottom: -23px; border:none" width="100%">
      <hr style="background-color: blue; height: 4px; position: relative; bottom: -11px; left:100px; border:none" width="80%">
      <hr style="background-color: purple; height: 4px; position: relative; bottom: 1px; left:200px; border:none" width="60%">                          
      <hr style="background-color: orange; height: 4px; position: relative; bottom: 13px; left:300px; border:none" width="40%">
      <hr style="background-color: green; height: 4px; position: relative; bottom: 25px; left:400px; border:none" width="20%">

     <nav id="mainnav">
        <ul style="border-left:green, dashed;">
          <li><a href="Index.html" class="thispagehome">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Properties Features.html">Features</a></li>
          <li><a href="Activities.html">Activities</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact US</a></li>
          <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

 </header>
    <h1 style="padding-top:30px" >Feline - Activities</h1>
    <hr class="style" width="50%">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="39%">d</td>
            <td width="61%">d</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dd</td>
            <td>dd</td>
         </tr>
     </table>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
    margin: 0px;
    color: #151515;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #EFF5F8;
}

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:530px;
    width:1000px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 740px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border:#6627C9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;

}

#slideshow img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#top {
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 65px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    color: #3399DD;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#mainimg img {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
h1, h2 {
    color: #3399CC;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 36px;
}

.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer {
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 2%;
    background-color: #43a6cb;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
}
a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
    color: #FF6600;
}

a:visited {
    color: #FF944C;
}

#mainnav a:hover  ,#mainnav a:active,#mainnav a:focus , #mainnav a.thispagehome{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: red;
}

#mainnav ul   {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
#mainnav a {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #4D4D4D;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}


#wrapper #main ul.horizontal li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style; none;
}

#wrapper #main .horizontal img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper #main ul.horizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style; none;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 25%;
}

img{
    display: block;
}

ul.horizontal {
    list-style; none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why there is a space between my hr and nav panel? Do `<hr>` tags automatically have some sort of padding? Anyone know how to fix this?

Also, if any knows how I can make it so that if you hover each link box separately that the background will be change to the colour of the hr line. (Check this link, I want it simular to that):

http://css-tricks.com

Comment: Please insert your code in the question itself. The reason you can't post a fiddle link without code isn't just for fun : your question must be understandable and answerable without that link.

Comment: Please edit your question to only reflect one topic. Post another question about colouring the hr line. That will make your question more clear, and have answers arrive faster on both your questions.

Comment: you can only ask one per 90 min

Comment: Then be patient. Don't crunch questions together for sake of time. Higher quality answers on separate questions help you and the SO community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/1md3phmo/5/

edits for hr:

```
 <hr style="background-color: red; height: 4px; border:none" width="20%">
  <hr style="background-color: blue; height: 4px;  border:none" width="20%">
  <hr style="background-color: purple; height: 4px;  bottom: 1px; border:none" width="20%">                          
  <hr style="background-color: orange; height: 4px; border:none" width="20%">
  <hr style="background-color: green; height: 4px;border:none" width="20%">
```

css

```
hr{float:left; margin:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the above problem adding this code in your css file:

```
#mainnav {
    margin-top: -33px;
}
```

NB: But remember, generally `<hr>` will take some space vertically if you do not use the following code in your css file (so always try this code in css if you use `<hr>` in your html):

```
hr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `hr` have some margin by default, which you don't remove.

Better use

```css
#top > hr {
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
#mainnav {
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
#top > hr {
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
#mainnav {
  clear: both;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  color: #151515;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #EFF5F8;
}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  height: 530px;
  width: 1000px;
}
#slideshow IMG {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 8;
}
#slideshow IMG.active {
  z-index: 10;
}
#slideshow IMG.last-active {
  z-index: 9;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 740px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: #6627C9;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#slideshow img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#top {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 65px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  color: #3399DD;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
#mainimg img {
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: #3399CC;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.centered {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
footer {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  background-color: #43a6cb;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
}
a {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
  color: #FF6600;
}
a:visited {
  color: #FF944C;
}
#mainnav a:hover,
#mainnav a:active,
#mainnav a:focus,
#mainnav a.thispagehome {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: red;
}
#mainnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#mainnav a {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#wrapper #main ul.horizontal li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
#wrapper #main .horizontal img {
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper #main ul.horizontal li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: justify;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 25%;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
ul.horizontal {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="top">
    <h1 style="font-size:60px">L'Auberge De Napoleon III</h1>
      <hr style="background-color: red">
      <hr style="background-color: blue">
      <hr style="background-color: purple">                          
      <hr style="background-color: orange">
      <hr style="background-color: green">
    <nav id="mainnav">
      <ul style="border-left:green, dashed;">
        <li><a href="Index.html" class="thispagehome">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Properties Features.html">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Activities.html">Activities</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact US</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Pricing.html">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <h1 style="padding-top:30px">Feline - Activities</h1>
  <hr class="style" width="50%">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="39%">d</td>
      <td width="61%">d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>dd</td>
      <td>dd</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```